# ffmpeg QSV hardware encoder with x11grab screen capture

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, intel, hardware-acceleration

I believe I have built ffmpeg with support for my motherboard's Intel graphics processor chip, but I have not succeeded in showing this working in any way. My goal is to use it for screen capture (the ffmpeg I built does capture screen successfully using the software encoding, but this is far too slow to be useful--it manages about 12fps at a very modest quality).

My main problem--I think--is that I don't know how to use these encoders, the examples I found all fail, which makes me suspect that what I've built is broken in some way. However, I also have no idea how I can verify that I built this correctly, but the following are true:

- The five components that I built to get to this all compiled without
  errors (they were libva, gmmlib, intel-media-driver, libmfx, and
  ffmpeg
- The output of ffmpeg -encoders includes four encoders with _qsv in
  their names including h264_qsv
- Most of the commands I have tried result in output of this form:

```
    [h264_qsv @ 0x55ef1dc72040] Low power mode is unsupported
    [h264_qsv @ 0x55ef1dc72040] Current frame rate is unsupported
    [h264_qsv @ 0x55ef1dc72040] Current picture structure is unsupported
    [h264_qsv @ 0x55ef1dc72040] Current resolution is unsupported
    [h264_qsv @ 0x55ef1dc72040] Current pixel format is unsupported
    [h264_qsv @ 0x55ef1dc72040] some encoding parameters are not supported by the QSV runtime. Please double check the input parameters.
    Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

I have the impression this thing might be fussy about many parameters of this sort but have no idea where to find out what it would like. Any suggestions at all, how to verify it, or better yet, how to issue a command that captures screen and encodes with the hardware, would be most welcome.

Comment: What CPU do you have, and what resolution / x264 settings are you using?  IIRC, even x264 `-preset veryslow` at 1920x1080 manages nearly 25fps on my i7-6700k at 4GHz, with Arch Linux's binary packages for libx264 and ffmpeg.  (At sane bitrates like `-crf 23`; the tradeoff is between CPU time and quality *per bitrate*; you can pump up the quality by spending bitrate and/or CPU time).  So anyway, a more modest CPU can probably capture + encode at a reasonable frame rate like 24, 25, or 30fps with `-preset medium` or `faster`, even with pure software, if you downscale to 1080p, if that helps.

Comment: It's an Intel Pentium Silver J5005 (on this motherboard: https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/J5005-ITX/index.asp) Currently it has a single 4Gb memory stick, but I have literally beside me waiting to be installed, a second stick, hoping that dual channel operation might help.

But I really want to get this thing to work with as much effort as possible offloaded onto the GPU; I have more important work for the CPU to do that can't be offloaded (just regular compute work).

Comment: Capturing a 1280x720 portion of the screen at 30fps, software encoding drops about half the frames and audio's useless (presumably because of the sync failures). Capturing a clock face shows the second hand running at roughly double speed. Occasionally there will be a "five second pause" between grabs.I admit I was shocked at this because this hardware was intended to be an upgrade from a Core2 Quad Q6600 (ancient!) that ran this encoding without noticable effort. However, that machine had a horribly loud fan, and since I was capturing audio with the screen grab, not acceptable.

Comment: Oh, that's low-power Silvermont family (specifically Goldmont Plus https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/cores/gemini_lake https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/128984/intel-pentium-silver-j5005-processor-4m-cache-up-to-2-80-ghz.html so no AVX).  Yeah IDK, x264 might not be well tuned at all for that microarchitecture.  And yeah, if you have other work for the CPU to do then software encoding isn't a long-term solution, I was mostly suggesting it as a sanity check on your setup.  Have you tried just encoding without capture, to rule out major slowdowns in the capture driver itself?

Comment: Actually, I have determined a number of things now that are "news" (at least to me :)
First, my original capture config in ffmpeg was "bad" (I find ffmpeg command lines utterly inscrutable, I'm afraid). Anyway, by changing things around, I'm able to get my 1280x720 capture running with very smooth video using software compression. However, it uses about 3 of the four cores to do this if much is moving (it's nearer to one core if nothing's happening to be fair :). Given that this motherboard *has* hardware encoding, I really just want to try to use that if I reasonably can.

Comment: oops (hit enter in mid stream). Anyway, I now know for sure that hardware encoding of some kind is happening, as I can make "something" work. But the quality is dreadful, and I'm struggling with knowing the right magic incantation (as mentioned, ffmpeg's commands are pretty much magic at the best of times, and this stuff seems to lack clear documentation to boot!)

Comment: So far, this runs 30fps, on 65% of a CPU, and produces ludicrously bad video (the kind of thing you'd use in a Star Trek movie to indicate that your antenna array has been blown off, and the Klingons are jamming your signal!)

ffmpeg -y -hwaccel vaapi -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -f alsa  -i pulse  -acodec ac3 -f x11grab -show_region 1 -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -i :0.0+100,100 -vf 'format=nv12,hwupload' -c:v h264_vaapi -qp 1 output.mp4

Comment: Notice this is the vaapi encoder. Nothing so far has made the qsv ones work at all.

Comment: Ok, so your FFmpeg install and graphics drivers aren't broken, you were just using it wrong.  That's the purpose I had in mind for testing with software encoding.  It makes sense that you don't want to use it for real.  I haven't used HW encoding at all, and I don't know if it's supposed to be possible with good quality on that hardware.  (And if so, whether that's possible with open source drivers or if good quality is only possible with some proprietary Intel software that can take advantage of the HW by doing something other than full offload.)  HW encoding historically has been poor.

Comment: If `-qp 1` is anything like what it means for x264, that's an insanely high quality setting and would produce extremely high bitrates.  Maybe the HW doesn't properly support that?  I'd try something like `-crf 18` or `-b:v 8000k` to give it lots of quality or bitrate, but not so high that it might hit weird corner cases in the HW or driver.  (Also, I'd use `libopus` for audio unless you specifically need AC3 for something.)